# Which objects are responsible for maintaining references between aggregates?

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, separation-of-concerns

Suppose I have one aggregate, `Ticket`. A `Ticket` will have one assigned `Department` and one or more assigned `Employee`.

1. When instantiating a `Ticket`, should a `TicketFactory` be responsible for ensuring that a `Ticket` is created with a valid/existent `Department` and `Employee`?
2. Likewise, when decommissioning a `Department` or `Employee`, what is responsible for ensuring that a new `Department` or `Employee` is assigned to a `Ticket` so as to maintain its invariants? Could there be a service in the domain responsible for decommissioning, or is this a case where eventual consistency or some form of event listening should be adopted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `TicketFactory` would be declare that in order to create a `Ticket` you need references to both a `Department` and an `Employee`. It would not verify that those actually exist. It would be the responsibility of the calling code to obtain the appropriate references.
2. If using eventual consistency, the decommissioning of a `Department` and `Employee` would publish events indicating the decommission. There would be a handler associated with a `Ticket` which would subscribe to that event and either assign a new department and employee or send some sort of warning to task.

Take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) for more on this.

Comment: I don't understand why exactly a factory would not handle ensuring that an aggregate contained valid references (or even un-guaranteed proxies). Could you please explain? Point 2 makes sense to me; I could already see multiple possible handlers for decommissioning an employee (sending an e-mail to other staff, moving a ticket to a queue pool, updating a directory.)

Comment: Also, thank you for the link -- I had read those writings some time before starting from home plate with Eric Evans' book. Thank you for reminding me of them, the second one in particular brings some things to mind, though I am not sure I agree with using global ids rather than object references (even if only a virtual proxy.) I will soon need to read Evans' book through again to see if I pick up anything else.

Comment: For a factory to be able to verify existence of other aggregates it would need access to their repositories - another dependency. Since application services already reference repositories or other services, they should be responsible for providing appropriate IDs.

Comment: I can almost grasp why one would use only the ID of another aggregate as Vernon recommends -- it eliminates dependencies, sure. But doesn't this also remove the responsibility of ensuring that all invariants are met from the domain and into the application layer? I thought the whole point of the domain layer was encapsulating all such business rules?

Comment: An aggregate is only responsible for its own invariants, not of other aggregates that it may reference. Having direct object references, as opposed to identity references, creates the possibility of two aggregates being modified in a single transaction. This can be problematic for various reasons.

Comment: Maybe I just didn't 'get' it at the time, but your answer is definitely the one.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started exploring DDD, so I have ran into some of the issues you mention.

1. I think that `TicketFactory` should always return validated/properly built `Ticket` instances. If you model is complex, you can have a domain service that validates that a given `Department` or `Employee` can be attached to it and then the factory uses it. Otherwise, you can just put it all in the factory. But what comes out of the factory should be a proper ticket.
2. I'd say that if e.g. only `Ticket` knows about the other two, a domain service that uses the `Department` and `Employee` repos would get the job done. If the relationship is bidirectional, then you can utilize event sourcing. Also, if it's really a event that should be captured in your domain model, and has other consequences other than reshuffling tickets, you can attach one of the handlers to this event to be `InvalidTicketHandler`. But if it's a small scale thing, keep it simple, just have a domain service that maintains the invariants.

Sidenote: If the `Department` and/or `Employee` are aggregates themselves, then you can reference them within `Ticket` via their identifier (e.g. employee's company ID or ID-code of the department). In that way you'll achieve consistency easier as you will not cross consistency boundaries between different aggregates.

Comment: 1. I agree, and this is a defining feature of a factory (that it produces a properly-assembled aggregate.) I thank you for your perspective; as I see it now, an added domain service could be of benefit should I add some constraints about how many projects may be assigned to an employee or department or something like that. 2. I am not at all sure how such a domain service would be called.

Comment: 2. In the process of decommissioning, what are the common usage scenarios? On a first look, there might be even more than one service that could be implemented. Maybe there could be a `EmployeeDecommissioner` service that would cover the case when an employee is fired (among other, I guess). And then you could have a `DepartmentDecommissioner` that could use `EmployeeDecommissioner` when a whole department is dismantled.
Best to do is to ask the domain experts for the right wording - perhaps they'd use

Comment: _perhaps they'd use..._ some other terms (didn't finish previous sentence, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

1. > A FACTORY is responsible for ensuring that all invariants are met for the object or AGGREGATE it creates; yet you should always think twice before removing the rules applying to an object outside that object. The FACTORY can delegate invariant checking to the product, and this is often best. [Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity at the Heart of Software]
2. A depends on question type, but from the look of it it seems like a great candidate for an application layer functionality, i wouldn't go for the event solution though cause i find it only suitable in between layers and not between objects in the same layer.